# List of All Magento 2 Configuration Files

Tags: magento2, xml, configuration, cli

Magento 2 uses XML-based configuration files A LOT. When studying Magento or preparing for an exam, it is useful to have a list of all config files used in Magento 2. How can such a list be generated? What are all configuration files used in the latest version 2.4.4?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a probably not optimal and not very nice bash one-liner:

```
find vendor/magento/ -type f -name '*.xml' | grep -v '/Test/' | grep -v '/dev/' | sed -n 's/.*etc\///p' | sort -n | uniq
```

It executes the following "steps":

1. Find all XML config files under `vendor/magento/`.
2. Exclude all XML files from `Test` directories.
3. Exclude all XML files from `dev` directories.
4. Only print everything after the `etc` directory. This also removes all entries without an `etc` directory.
5. Sort the matches alphabetically.
6. Make the resulting list unique.

Here is a list of all XML configuration files used in Magento 2.4.4:

```
acl.xml
address_formats.xml
adminhtml/csp_whitelist.xml
adminhtml/di.xml
adminhtml/events.xml
adminhtml/menu.xml
adminhtml/routes.xml
adminhtml/rules/payment_au.xml
adminhtml/rules/payment_ca.xml
adminhtml/rules/payment_de.xml
adminhtml/rules/payment_es.xml
adminhtml/rules/payment_fr.xml
adminhtml/rules/payment_gb.xml
adminhtml/rules/payment_hk.xml
adminhtml/rules/payment_it.xml
adminhtml/rules/payment_jp.xml
adminhtml/rules/payment_nz.xml
adminhtml/rules/payment_other.xml
adminhtml/rules/payment_us.xml
adminhtml/system/express_checkout.xml
adminhtml/system/payflow_advanced.xml
adminhtml/system/payflow_link.xml
adminhtml/system/payments_pro_hosted_solution_with_express_checkout.xml
adminhtml/system/payments_pro_hosted_solution.xml
adminhtml/system/paypal_payflowpro_with_express_checkout.xml
adminhtml/system/paypal_payflowpro.xml
adminhtml/system.xml
analytics.xml
cache.xml
catalog_attributes.xml
communication.xml
config.xml
countries.xml
cron_groups.xml
crontab/di.xml
crontab/events.xml
crontab.xml
csp_whitelist.xml
data_source/website.xml
db_schema.xml
definition.map.xml
definition.xml
directory.xml
di.xml
eav_attributes.xml
email_templates.xml
esconfig.xml
events.xml
export.xml
extension_attributes.xml
fieldset.xml
frontend/di.xml
frontend/events.xml
frontend/page_types.xml
frontend/routes.xml
frontend/sections.xml
graphql/di.xml
graphql/events.xml
import.xml
indexer.xml
media_content.xml
module.xml
mview.xml
payment.xml
pdf.xml
persistent.xml
product_options.xml
product_types.xml
queue_consumer.xml
queue_publisher.xml
queue_topology.xml
queue.xml
reports.xml
resources.xml
sales.xml
search_engine.xml
search_request.xml
validation.xml
view.xml
webapi_async.xml
webapi_rest/di.xml
webapi_rest/events.xml
webapi_soap/di.xml
webapi_soap/events.xml
webapi.xml
widget.xml
zip_codes.xml
```

The DevDocs also list some [configuration files with references to the respective PHP class](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/config/config-files.html#config-files-classes-objects). However, it looks like this list is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

Here you find the list of configuration files in magento 2:

app/etc/config.php — contains the declaration of all modules;

app/etc/env.php — describes the array, which contains the front-end name for the back-end panel, the data for connection to the database, the table prefixes, the current store mode, and the types and statuses of the cache.

etc/config.xml — contains default option values from Stores > Configuration in the admin panel menu. This menu can be configured at system.xml;

di.xml — contains configurations for the dependency injection;

etc/events.xml — a list of observers and events;

etc/routes.xml — a list of routers;

etc/config.xml — contains the default values for the module settings Stores > Configuration;

etc/acl.xml — adds module resources to a resource tree that allows you to configure access for different users.

etc/crontab.xml — adds and configures the task for the cronjob;

etc/module.xml — announces the name and the version of the module, as well as its dependencies on other modules;

etc/widget.xml — stores the widget settings;

etc/indexer.xml — announces a new kind of indexing. It specifies the view_id parameter, which points at the views described in etc/mview.xml;

etc/mview.xml —  describes the representations of all the indices described in etc/indexer.xml;

etc/webapi.xml — defines web API components, which service method to use and which resource to connect for a specific request;

etc/view.xml — contains the properties of product images;

etc/product_types.xml — describes types of products in a store;

etc/product_options.xml — describes the types of options, that can have products and classes to render them;

etc/extension_attributes.xml — a new ability to add a custom attribute appeared in Magento 2. This file describes the attribute, its type, which can be simple or complex and represent an interface;

etc/catalog_attributes.xml — groups attributes;

etc/adminhtml/system.xml — can only apply to the admin area, adds tabs to Stores > Configuration, describes sections and fields of a form;

etc/adminhtml/menu.xml — can only apply to the admin area, adds an item to the admin panel menu.

Magento downloads different files and different areas separately. It has various loaders for each type of files.

you can follow the doc: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/config/config-files.html